# Need a help in understanding theorem 6.1 in chapter 2 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation, riesz-representation-theorem

The theorem and its proof is given in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I could not understand:

**$Q_{1}$** the line after equation(1), why $f_{i}(x)$ is given by the indicated form for all i?, and why it is a bounded linear functional?

**$Q_{2}$** why the representation of $K$ is not unique?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_{i}(x)=\left<Kx,\varphi_{i}\right>$ is simply by definition. To see that it is bounded, we have $|f_{i}(x)|\leq\|Kx\|\|\varphi_{i}\|=\|Kx\|\leq\|K\|\|x\|$. Note that $K$ is bounded by assumption.

Comment: I think $i,j$ are mixed up?  They should all be $i$.

Comment: which definition ? the book did not mention any definition except what is given by Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: The author defined $f_{i}$ to be $f_{i}(x)=\left<Kx,\varphi_{i}\right>$.

Comment: why he defined it in this shape ?

Comment: I have added a question, could you please answer it ?

Comment: That is a shortcut, because he didn't want to write $\left<Kx,\varphi_{i}\right>$ everytime, and $\left<Kx,\varphi_{i}\right>$ as linear map of $x$, is bounded, hence Riesz applies.

Comment: For different set of orthonormal basis $\{\psi_{1},...,\psi_{n}\}$, the corresponding Riesz vectors $w_{i}$ are not equal to $v_{i}$, still, we have $Kx=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left<x,\psi_{i}\right>w_{i}$.

Comment: I think $\psi _{i}$ should be interchanged with $w_i$ in your last comment ....am I right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that typo.

Comment: Thank you for your so clear explanation :)